# PHP first fwrite() to socket closed by remote server throws no error

Tags: php, sockets, fwrite

PHP version: 5.4.4 on Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64. I'm using stream sockets.
I created simple server and client applications to illustrate my issue:

```
<?php
$client = false;
$server_sock = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:20015", $errNo, $errorMessage);
if ($server_sock == false) die("Could not bind to socket: {$errNo} - {$errorMessage}"); 
while (true) { 
    if ($client !== false) {
        if (feof($client)) $data = false;
        else $data = stream_get_contents($client);
        if ($data === false) {
            fclose($client);
            $client = false;
            echo "Client disconnected\n";
            continue;
        } else if ($data === "") continue;
        echo "Received: " . $data . "\n";            
    } else {
        $clients = array($server_sock);
        $num_streams = stream_select($clients, $write = null, $except = null, 0, 200000);
        if ($num_streams > 0) {
            if (in_array($server_sock, $clients)) {
                $client = stream_socket_accept($server_sock);
                if ($client) {
                    if(!stream_set_blocking($client, 0)) echo "stream_set_blocking() error\n";
                } else {
                    echo "stream_socket_accept() error\n";
                    $client = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Client code:

```
<?php
    $client = stream_socket_client("tcp://127.0.0.1:20015", $errNo, $errorMessage);
    if ($client == false) die("Could not connect to server: {$errNo} - {$errorMessage}\n");
    if(!stream_set_blocking($client, 0)) echo "stream_set_blocking() error\n";

    $tick = true;

    while (true) {
        sleep(2);
        if ($tick) $toSend = "TICK "; else $toSend = "TOCK ";
        $tick = !$tick;
        $toSend .= time();
        $num_bytes = fwrite($client, $toSend);
        if ($num_bytes === false || $num_bytes < strlen($toSend)) { echo "fwrite() error\n"; continue; }
        else echo "Data sent: {$toSend}. Bytes: {$num_bytes}\n";
    }
    if (fclose($client)) echo "Socket closed\n";
    else echo "fclose() error\n";
?>
```

The problem: if I manually shutdown server (to simulate lost connection), first fwrite() call (on the client side) after server shutdown throws no error. Calling fwrite() second time returns 0 and generates PHP notice "PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe" as expected. Everything sent with first fwrite() call is lost but client "thinks" that everything is OK. In production environment, after error client will try to reconnect and if it succeed, it will try to resend data. But here client is not fully aware of sitaution. Why fwrite() behaves like this? I was trying to enable blocking mode on the stream with timeout, fwrite() and then get stream meta data, but it seems that fwrite() never times out, even if it gives error. Any tips or solutions?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem right now. Have you found anything on your problem? I am running ubuntu with CakePHP using sockets with fwrite.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented simple ACK protocol. Server must respond with ACK message to every commnd it receives, so client knows whether server received it or not. When there is no ACK, client assumes that connection is broken, which is true if you implement that solution correctly.